# PYQT Accessing and changing dynamically added controls

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am a beginner with GUI's and PYQT. What I am trying to do is dynamically set up a grid of QComboBox's and QLineEdit's. From the QComboBox you can select a choice and from that choice, it will fill in the corresponding QLineEdit with some numbers. The problem I'm having is creating the link between the first QComboBox and the first QLineEdit box. I could make a function for each row but I would like to know a better way. I will post some sample code. Thank you for any help or advice that you might have.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 700, 600)

        self.home()

    def home(self):
        Test1Choices = ['Test1:','Choice1', 'Choice2', 'Choice3', 'Choice4','Choice5', 'Choice6', 'Choice7', 'Choice8', 'Choice9']
        Test2Choices= ['Test2:','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15']
        for i in range(0,10):
            Choice1ComboBox = QComboBox(self)
            Choice1ComboBox.addItems(Test1Choices)
            Choice1ComboBox.resize(150,25)
            Choice1ComboBox.move(30,(150+(i*35)))
            Choice1ComboBox.setCurrentIndex(2)

            Choice2ComboBox = QComboBox(self)
            Choice2ComboBox.setObjectName("Choice2ComboBox"+str(i))
            Choice2ComboBox.addItems(Test2Choices)
            Choice2ComboBox.resize(75,25)
            Choice2ComboBox.move(200,(150+(i*35)))
            Choice2ComboBox.setCurrentIndex(2)
            Choice2ComboBox.activated[str].connect(self.doSomething)

            numTextBox = QLineEdit(self)
            numTextBox.setObjectName("numBox"+str(i))
            numTextBox.move(325,(150+(i*35)))
            numTextBox.resize(35,25)

            result1TextBox = QLineEdit(self)
            result1TextBox.setObjectName("result1Box"+str(i))
            result1TextBox.move(400,(150+(i*35)))
            result1TextBox.resize(100,25)
            result1TextBox.setEnabled(0)

            result2TextBox = QLineEdit(self)
            result2TextBox.setObjectName("result2Box"+str(i))
            result2TextBox.move(525,(150+(i*35)))
            result2TextBox.resize(100,25)
            result2TextBox.setEnabled(0)

        self.show()

    def doSomething(self):
        numbers=['result1','result2','result3','result4','result5','result6','result7','result8','result9','result10','result11','result12','result13','result14','result15']

def run():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    Gui = window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


run()
```

To summarize I would like to  bring in the index of the selected `QComboBox`. Then use that index number to reference the answer that is in the "numbers" array. Then print that result in the `QLineEdit` that is in the same row

Comment: I see that you have 2 columns of combobox, one column of QLineEdit and another 2 columns of QLineEdit disabled, what relationship there is between them. Your description there is nothing about them.

Comment: This is for calculating the overall area for a group of wires. The first combobox is for insulation type for each wire, while the second combobox is the wire size. So if you have a THWN for the insulation type and the size is 12awg then 0.0133 should appear in the first disabled QLineEdit in the same row. I tried to change the code to make it more generic.

Comment: The other QLineEdits disabled will not you use them? You only want to use the 2 QComboBox and QLineEdit.

Comment: Sorry I realize that was not clear, I was trying to edit it and my computer shut down to install updates. But the first combobox is for the insulation type for a wire. The second combobox is for the wire size. The first QLineEdit is for the user to input a number of wires they have. The first disabled QLineEdit should print out the size of an individual wire that was selected and the last QLineEdit should be the Area of one wire * the amount

Comment: I guess the inputs are the 2 QComboBox and the QLineEdit enabled, and the outputs are the last 2 QLineEdits disabled, am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use `sender()` to get the object that emits the signal, then we look for the name of that object with `setObjectName()`, and we search the index, then we get the other objects with `findChildren()`, for example the output will be the union of the selected texts.

add name to Choice1ComboBox:

```
Choice1ComboBox.setObjectName("Choice1ComboBox"+str(i))
```

doSomething function:

```
def doSomething(self, _):
    sender = self.sender()

    l = sender.objectName().split("Choice1ComboBox")
    if len(l) > 1:
        number = l[1]
    else:
        number = sender.objectName().split("Choice2ComboBox")[1]

    combo1 = self.findChildren(QComboBox, "Choice1ComboBox"+number)[0]
    combo2 = self.findChildren(QComboBox, "Choice2ComboBox"+number)[0]
    obj = self.findChildren(QLineEdit, "numBox"+number)[0]
    obj.setText(combo1.currentText() + " " +  combo2.currentText())
```

Complete code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 700, 600)

        self.home()

    def home(self):
        Test1Choices = ['Test1:','Choice1', 'Choice2', 'Choice3', 'Choice4','Choice5', 'Choice6', 'Choice7', 'Choice8', 'Choice9']
        Test2Choices= ['Test2:','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15']
        for i in range(0,10):
            Choice1ComboBox = QComboBox(self)
            Choice1ComboBox.setObjectName("Choice1ComboBox"+str(i))
            Choice1ComboBox.addItems(Test1Choices)
            Choice1ComboBox.resize(150,25)
            Choice1ComboBox.move(30,(150+(i*35)))
            Choice1ComboBox.setCurrentIndex(2)
            Choice1ComboBox.activated[str].connect(self.doSomething)

            Choice2ComboBox = QComboBox(self)
            Choice2ComboBox.setObjectName("Choice2ComboBox"+str(i))
            Choice2ComboBox.addItems(Test2Choices)
            Choice2ComboBox.resize(75,25)
            Choice2ComboBox.move(200,(150+(i*35)))
            Choice2ComboBox.setCurrentIndex(2)
            Choice2ComboBox.activated[str].connect(self.doSomething)

            numTextBox = QLineEdit(self)
            numTextBox.setObjectName("numBox"+str(i))
            numTextBox.move(325,(150+(i*35)))
            numTextBox.resize(35,25)

            result1TextBox = QLineEdit(self)
            result1TextBox.setObjectName("result1Box"+str(i))
            result1TextBox.move(400,(150+(i*35)))
            result1TextBox.resize(100,25)
            result1TextBox.setEnabled(0)

            result2TextBox = QLineEdit(self)
            result2TextBox.setObjectName("result2Box"+str(i))
            result2TextBox.move(525,(150+(i*35)))
            result2TextBox.resize(100,25)
            result2TextBox.setEnabled(0)

        self.show()

    def doSomething(self, _):
        sender = self.sender()

        l = sender.objectName().split("Choice1ComboBox")
        if len(l) > 1:
            number = l[1]
        else:
            number = sender.objectName().split("Choice2ComboBox")[1]

        combo1 = self.findChildren(QComboBox, "Choice1ComboBox"+number)[0]
        combo2 = self.findChildren(QComboBox, "Choice2ComboBox"+number)[0]
        obj = self.findChildren(QLineEdit, "numBox"+number)[0]
        obj.setText(combo1.currentText() +  " " + combo2.currentText())




def run():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    Gui = window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


run()
```

Comment: That is it! Thank you so much!! I have spent more time than I would like to admit trying to figure it out. I appreciate all your help!